# How to create push notification using the Rest API in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, push-notification

I am learning flutter. I want to create push notification in flutter app using the data from Rest API.

When any data come in API .there should i get push notification. Can i achieve without firebase and let me know the whole process?

Answer (score 0):

If not using firebase, i dont think it will work smooth as using firebase

I think your option is to use local notification, but you must have some mechanism to keep listen to the data from API

But ... I would recommend to use firebase

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Any link for that?